# Using $system to run awk command

Tags: system-verilog, verification

I have an input file which has a few characters in it ('ABCDABCD'),
and I'm trying to use `awk` inside SystemVerilog to create an output file which is written like this:

```
00000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000
00ABCDABCD0000000000000000000000
```

I tried using this line:

```
$system("awk '{print "00000000000000000000000000000000"; print "00000000000000000000000000000000"; print "00000000000000000000000000000000" ;print "00"$1"0000000000000000000000"}' input.hex > output.hex");
```

But, I keep getting the message:

> expecting a right parenthesis

Any ideas why and what should I fix?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with the double quotes.  You need to use the backslash character to escape all of the double quotes, **except for the first and last quotes**:

```
$system("awk '{print \"00000000000000000000000000000000\"; print \"00000000000000000000000000000000\"; print \"00000000000000000000000000000000\" ;print \"00\"$1\"0000000000000000000000\"}' input.hex > output.hex");
//      |no escape                                                                                                                                                                                         no escape|
```

Comment: For those who are running through `bash -c`, you must escape the first and last quotes.